Recent Zombie apocalypse E-book or Web novel. MC at a college rescues a couple girls then they head to Gym where other students have gathered
I believe it was written in the last few years, probably not more that 5-6 years ago. I think I read it in the last 6 months?
I can not recall if it was a web novel or and e-book. It was probably Not a translated Asian light novel. The English was well written and not poorly Google translated broken English. I do not recall any leveling system or stats improvement cultivation in the story.
MC is in college when a zombie apocalypse breaks out. (I think he wakes up in his dorm and is late for a test in his computer class. Maybe one of his classmates called him, waking him up, to ask why he was not in class.) In any case, it's about this time is when the outbreak occurs.
His dorm is pretty empty, since everyone is in class. As he is hurrying down the stairs in his dorm, he rescues a girl who is being attacked. Later he rescues a second one. (Maybe a friend of the first who knew second was still asleep(?) in her own dorm room, so they went there to get her.)
The campus and nearby town/city is crawling with zombies. But the zombies are slow and not focused. If they see or hear something they will go after it, but once they loose sight or sound of it they stop. (Close a door, they do not pound on it to break it down, they just mill around.)
Later they hear on the cell phones that many of their classmates have gathered in the Gym. So they go there. Some of the people in the computer classes made it there, (about 30-40 people?) and another group of people from another subject matter (Arts? Poly-Sci?) also made it there. (About twice as many as computer students, 60-80 people.) It is mentioned several times about the animosity between these two class disciplines. Classic Nerds vs the Elites.
On the way to the gym the MC and 2 girls were able to grab 2 backpacks/large gym bags and fill them with food. (They finished looting a minimart, or the 2nd girl had food in her room.)
The people in the gym are low on food, and aggressively complaining they need to share the food. So the MC gives one of the bags of food to the Poly-Sci group. They were already sharing the first one with their friends in the computer class.
The MC proposes they run a few people on a scavenging run for food using bicycles to a store about 1/2 mile away, The Poly-Sci group leader objects and wants to send a large group (10-12 people) to a cafeteria nearby. They cant agree, so 2 groups go out.
The MC and a few students use bikes (quiet and fast) on a back road to get to the store. But stop in a nearby shop with a steel roll up door that was not quite closed to scope out the store they wanted to loot. Inside the shop they kill the shop owner who had turned and find his daughter (6-yrs old?) locked in the back room, but its filled with food/snacks which they grab instead of going to the store. They return back to the gym with a full load and the little girl. (Maybe one of them died on the return, cant remember.) I think they also picked up either a gun or bows and arrows.
Meanwhile The large group went to the cafeteria, to raid the kitchen/storeroom. But those were all the way in the back, and by they time they were half way across the cafeteria, they realized the place was full of zombies. (Which the MC pointed out was a strong possibility.) Only 2 made it back to the gym, the Poly-Sci leader and another (who had been bitten but had not turned yet) with no supplies.
This time the computer students were less willing to share, and arguing broke out and the Poly-Sci students started attacking and grabbing the food. About this time the Student who had been bitten turned and started attacking students. The violent fight turned into a riot when the students realized someone has turned and is killing people.
They eventually kill all the zombies, but not before loosing 1/3? 1/2? of the students between the fight and the zombies. Then they are all standing around watching each other looking to see if someone else got bit, won't admitted it, and has not turned yet. A lot of tension in the air, and maybe a revenge kill, "Oh. He is turning!!" club him in the head with a baseball bat, before anyone else realizes he wasn't
This was as far as I got in the story.

I found it. It is a YouTube Asian Light Novel narration.
The story on YouTube is called:
"After Oversleeping, Zombies Broke Out On Campus"
5 videos covering Chapter 1-327 where story ends. (~45 hours)



It is most likely an English translation of a Chinese Light Novel/Web Novel.
I have actually listened to several of the Apocalypse stories on this channel. And while entertaining, the translation are a bit lacking.
The story pretty much follows what I described in the original post. I only listened to about the first 20-25 chapters.
While some of these Asian light novel narration channels do post the original name (and/or the English translation of the name) so you can find it on line and read along, this channel never posts the name of the original story. So this is the only source I have found for the story.
EDIT: The MC is a girl, not a guy like I thought in the original question

Possibly Zombie University by Trip Ellington.


What Happens When a College University is Overrun By Zombies?
They’re outside the door… I hear them. I hear their dead legs dragging their limp feet down the hallway outside my dorm room. I used to go to class with a few of them… you know… before it happened. I’d be fine with keeping them on one side of the door and me on the other except for one little problem… I’m all out of food and I can see the school cafeteria from my window. Oh yeah, one more thing… They’re hungry too.
My name is Sam and my university is full of zombies.

The only review (1 star!) mentions many of the points you remember. For example it starts with Sam in the dorm:

We get an introduction to our hero Sam who is a nice guy and I loved that the author decided to give him a limp related to having cerebral palsy. This means Sam has difficulty with stairs, can't outrun zombies and tires more easily. This is why he has been trapped in his dorm since the outbreak began.

And it mentions him rescuing the girl Lana:

Sam is only being forced to leave the dorm because he needs food and on his way to the cafeteria he rescues Lana, a pre-med student. Later they hook up with a range of other survivors. Gabby the fat girl, Neal, Morgan the hysterical, a professor and Sam's roomie Tom.


No this is not the same book, It is a totally different story.
